# What does void actually mean? How is it usable in this weird way?

Tags: c, void

I've heard quite a bit about this line: `void typedef name`.

Compiles well:

```
void typedef name;
int main(){}
```

What does `void` even mean? Doesn't it just mean that something is just void? How can it be used before a keyword like `typedef`? Isn't it invalid use of `void`? It seems to be the same as doing:

```
typedef void name;
```

And makes `name` an alias for `void`.
Does the compiler rearrange `typedef` and `void`?

I thought `void` is only usable with functions:

```
void func();
```

But for what things can `void` be used and what does it mean? And how does `void typedef name` work even though it's not a function declaration?

Comment: In a typedef declaration, the keyword `typedef` can be before, during or after the type specifier  . It's conventional to put it at the start of the line .  You can use this typedef in your suggested example, e.g. `typedef void name;  name func();`  is the same as `void func();`

Comment: @ikegami I didn't get any warnings with gcc 9.4.0.

Comment: @ikegami Ooops, I fixed the typos. Nice joke. Anyways, now what? What about this actually intended code? This works very fine. And it makes `name` as an alias of `void`.

Comment: @M.M I know `name` becomes and alias of `void` from experiments. That's why I theorized that it may have rearranged `void` and `typedef`. My theory is somewhat correct according to you. More like both syntaxes work?

Comment: I encourage you to find a copy of the C standard, and try to answer your own question. It's not so easy at first, but it yields authoritative results (where experiments don't).

Comment: Section 6.7.7 describes the (weird) way that typedef behaves. You'll have to look up other referenced sections from there to get the conclusion that @M.M helpfully provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, a *declaration* is one or more *declaration-specifiers* followed by a list of *declarators* with optional *initializers*. Humans tend to write the specifiers in a particular order, but the C grammar allows them to be written in any order. They are:

- *storage-class-specifier*: `typedef`, `extern`, `static`, `_Thread_local`, `auto`, and `register`.
- *type-specifier*: `void`, `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, `signed`, `unsigned`, `_Bool`, `_Complex`, `_Atomic (type-name)`, and structure specifiers, union specifiers, enum specifiers, and (previously defined) typedef names.
- *type-qualifier*: `const`, `restrict`, `volatile`, and `_Atomic`.
- *function-specifier*: `inline` and `_Noreturn`.
- *alignment-specifier*: `_Alignas (type-name)` and `_Alignas (constant-expression)`.

There are some rules about how many times various specifiers may appear and rules about which may appear with which. However, there is no rule about the order in which they appear. So all of the above can be rearranged as desired. That includes putting some of the specifiers in between the *type-specifiers* that we normally group together, such as `const long static int _Alignas (double) long signed x;`, which contains `signed long long int` in a confusing way. The compiler does not care; it remembers everything and figures it out.

So `void typedef name` is the same as `typedef void name`; it defines `name` to be an alias for `void`.

As you can see from the list above, `void` is a *type-specifier*. Quite simply, it specifies a type. That type is defined to be *incomplete*, meaning it has no defined size. Further, the C standard specifies it cannot be completed; no size can be given to it. The fact that it has no size serves to prevent programs from accidentally referring to `void` objects: If `p` is a `void *`, then `*p` would refer to a `void` object, and, if a program actually attempts to access it, the compiler should issue a diagnostic message.

### Supplementary Note

The *declarators* in a declaration are the things built around identifiers being declared:

- A plain *identifier*.
- A *declarator* followed brackets `[` and `]` to indicate an array, with various options for inside the brackets.
- A *declarator* followed by parentheses `(` and `)` to indicate a function, with various options for inside the parentheses.
- A *declarator* preceded by `*` to indicate a pointer, optionally with *type-qualifiers* (like `const`) between the `*` and the declarator.
- A *declarator* inside parentheses, to override the default grouping in complicated *declarators* mixing pointers and arrays and such.

Answer (score 3):

`typedef` is by syntax a *storage class specifier*, of which there can only be one in the declaration specifiers (except _Thread_local).

The order of declaration spcifiers (the "T", not the "D" part of a declaration) is free - most put `const char` and not `char const`. But e.g. `char const*const x` is also used.

Semantically, `typedef` creates "only" a synonym for the given type. So yes, the compiler does rearrange (parses that declaration)

While a `void x;` declaration gives an error, it compiles with a `typedef`. Depends how you use it later e.g. for a pointer:

```
   typedef void _0;
    _0 *y;
```

Even though `_0* y` is the same, the position of the `*` can not be switched. It is on the left of the declarator ("D") giving `T*D` with all white-space variations.